# positioning text in tikz drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf

All,

I'd like to position my text in a tikz picture such that it does not interfere with the lines drawn. I am new to tikz so bear with me on the coding.

This is my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture} % STYLES \tikzset{
    ellips/.style={ellipse, minimum width=100pt,
    align=center,node distance=3cm,fill=black!10,inner sep=5pt,text width=2.5cm,minimum 
    height=2.0cm,>=stealth'} }

\node [ellips](Choices) {Strategic Choices}; 
\node [above=2cm of Choices](dummy) {}; 
\node [ellips, force, left=1.5cm of dummy] (Institutions) {Institutions}; 
\node [ellips, force, right=1.5cm of dummy] (Organisations) {Organisations};

% Draw the links between  
\path[<->,thick]   
     (Choices) edge node[anchor=center, text width=3.5cm, left, midway] {Industry conditions and firm-specific resources}  (Institutions)   
     (Choices) edge node[anchor=center, text width=3.5cm, right, midway] {Formal and informal constraints} (Organisations)  
     (Institutions) edge  node [midway, below] {interaction} node[midway, above] {Dynamic} (Organisations);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives the following result

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `auto` placement tries to guess the best positioning for a node in a path, so that the text of the node does not overlap the path.

In general `auto` to puts the text at the left of the direction in which the path is traversed. So for the path from `(Institutions)` to `(Organization)`, `auto` will put the text above. For the path from `(Choices)` to `(Institutions)`, it will use `below left`, and for the path from `(Choices)` to `(Organizations)` it will use `above left`.

Since the last one is not what we want, we can draw the last path from `(Organizations)` to `(Choices)`, instead, to get the text at the desired place:

```
%In the preamble
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}[force/.style={},
    ellips/.style={ellipse, minimum width=100pt,
    align=center,node distance=3cm,fill=black!10,inner sep=5pt,text width=2.5cm,minimum 
    height=2.0cm,>=stealth'}
]

\node [ellips](Choices) {Strategic Choices}; 
\node [above=2cm of Choices](dummy) {}; 
\node [ellips, force, left=1.5cm of dummy] (Institutions) {Institutions}; 
\node [ellips, force, right=1.5cm of dummy] (Organisations) {Organisations};

% Draw the links between  
\path[<->,thick]   
     (Choices) edge node[anchor=center, text width=3.5cm, auto, midway] {Industry conditions and firm-specific resources}  (Institutions)   
     (Organisations) edge node[anchor=center, text width=3.5cm, auto, midway] {Formal and informal constraints} (Choices)  
     (Institutions) edge  node [midway, below] {interaction} node[above, midway] {Dynamic} (Organisations);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 13):

You can use `below left` and `below right`. But make sure your MWE is compilable. It's missing many items required.

```
%In the preamble
% \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}[force/.style={},
    ellips/.style={ellipse, minimum width=100pt,
    align=center,node distance=3cm,fill=black!10,inner sep=5pt,text width=2.5cm,minimum 
    height=2.0cm,>=stealth'}
]

\node [ellips](Choices) {Strategic Choices}; 
\node [above=2cm of Choices](dummy) {}; 
\node [ellips, force, left=1.5cm of dummy] (Institutions) {Institutions}; 
\node [ellips, force, right=1.5cm of dummy] (Organisations) {Organisations};

% Draw the links between  
\path[<->,thick]   
     (Choices) edge node[anchor=center, text width=3.5cm, below left, midway] {Industry conditions and firm-specific resources}  (Institutions)   
     (Choices) edge node[anchor=center, text width=3.5cm, below right, midway] {Formal and informal constraints} (Organisations)  
     (Institutions) edge  node [midway, below] {interaction} node[midway, above] {Dynamic} (Organisations);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]